representing firing rates of a neuron using delta functions [computational neuroscience]
I'm reading 'fundamentals of computaional neuroscience' by Thomas P. Trappenberg and was confused while reading about representing firing rates using direc delta functions.
instantaneous firing rate described in the book
In the book, the instantaneous firing rate is described as above, and the author states that the tf is the firing time of the neuron. However, since spike trains can be represented as the sum of delta functions, i thought the formula should've been
what i think the instantaneous firing rate should look like
where n is the total number of spikes and ti is the firing time of the neuron.
I think i'm missing something here; how can you represent the instantaneous firing rate using only a single delta function?
Please help..

Yours is correct, theirs is wrong.

Oh. Thank you for answering.

Would have been nice if you had taken the time to at least rotate the pictures so that your readers have an easier time with them...

Sorry for the inconvenience. Edited just now
